# Deploying GitLab from GCP Marketplace: BackoffLimitExceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy an instance of GitLab from the [GCP Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/gitlab-public/gitlab?filter=solution-type:k8s) but have run into a problem. Unfortunately, I am a mere front-end developer so this Kubernetes stuff is alien to me.

After creating the cluster, all of the components appear to succeed, with the exception of the job `gitlab-deployer` which fails with the error message:

> BackoffLimitExceeded

Now I can imagine what this means, but I do not know! Where would I get support for installing stuff from the Marketplace, or can anyone explain what this error means and how I go about fixing it? Is it not possible to just re-run this job?

Comment: Please also provide details on your GKE version you're running it on.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Any progress with this issue ? Did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get more details on what actually happened by running:

```
kubectl describe job gitlab-deployer
```

and then take a look at the `events` section.

`BackoffLimitExceeded` status of the job basically means that **kubernetes** (or more specifically job controller) tried to run this **job** however each time unsuccessfully.

There is a limit of retries which defaults to 6 and when it is reached such job is considered as failed. More on that you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#pod-backoff-failure-policy):

> There are situations where you want to fail a Job after some amount of
>   retries due to a logical error in configuration etc. To do so, set
>   `.spec.backoffLimit` to specify the number of retries before
>   considering a Job as failed. The back-off limit is set by default to
>   6. Failed Pods associated with the Job are recreated by the Job controller with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s …) capped
>   at six minutes. The back-off count is reset if no new failed Pods
>   appear before the Job’s next status check.

Please share the details I asked you for by editing your question so we can take a closer look at it and figure out what the actual issue is. Maybe it simply needs some configuration change.